# Different directory size after rsync and using du

Tags: rsync, disk-usage, synology

I migrated some special directories (not supported by common migration tools) from one Synology NAS volume (ext4) to another (btrfs). After checking if the synchronization was successful I found that sizes differ a lot.

I understand that there are block size differences but `du` gives me wrong data size within the same volume.

The total size of the whole directory is more than 1 TB so I narrowed the commands below to a smaller sub-directory.

Different sizes:

```
sudo du -sm /volume[12]/@synologydrive/@sync/repo/1/2
11418   /volume1/@synologydrive/@sync/repo/1/2
11122   /volume2/@synologydrive/@sync/repo/1/2
```

But for each sub-directory I get correct sizes (more or less when bytes are used) - sub-directory `n` is selected:

```
sudo du -sm /volume[12]/@synologydrive/@sync/repo/1/2/n
295     /volume1/@synologydrive/@sync/repo/1/2/n
295     /volume2/@synologydrive/@sync/repo/1/2/n

sudo du -sb /volume[12]/@synologydrive/@sync/repo/1/2/n
308387853       /volume1/@synologydrive/@sync/repo/1/2/n
308391693       /volume2/@synologydrive/@sync/repo/1/2/n
```

But, I'm getting completely different sizes when `*` is used (i.e. even on the same volume compare command above and this one on volume2):

```
sudo du -sm /volume[12]/@synologydrive/@sync/repo/1/2/* | grep n$
295     /volume1/@synologydrive/@sync/repo/1/2/n
200     /volume2/@synologydrive/@sync/repo/1/2/n

sudo du -sb /volume[12]/@synologydrive/@sync/repo/1/2/* | grep n$
308387853       /volume1/@synologydrive/@sync/repo/1/2/n
209533219       /volume2/@synologydrive/@sync/repo/1/2/n
```

I also counted sizes of all files under the `n` directory and I'm getting the same sizes:

```
ls -lA /volume1/@synologydrive/@sync/repo/1/2/n | tr -s ' ' | cut -f5 -d" " | awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}'
308387597
ls -lA /volume2/@synologydrive/@sync/repo/1/2/n | tr -s ' ' | cut -f5 -d" " | awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}'
308387597
```

So, it seems that the directories are "rsynced" correctly (same number of files, same sizes) and tried to exclude differences between two different file systems. But `du` gives me significantly bigger size on new volume1 (or more exactly - significantly smaller on old volume2).

Do you have any explanation for it?

**Notes:**

- `volume1` is new btrfs target volume (I copied data to)
- `volume2` is old ext4 source volume (I copied data from)
- Data were copied using `sudo rsync -a --progress --delete /volume2/@synologydrive /volume1`

Comment: Do you have sparse files and/or hard-linked files? Ho did you run the `rsync` command? Did you include `--sparse` and `--hard-links`? It also matters how you count the sizes that you compare.  For sparse files, you either count the apparent sizes (shown by `ls` by default), or you count the actual size (number of bytes on disk). For hard-linked files `du` would only count a file once.

Comment: @they, `rsync` command is mentioned above in Notes. There are no hard-links (AFAIK). I also tried `rsync` with `--sparse` switch but no change. However, the core of the question is probably not in rsync itself as the sizes differ on the source volume - there are differences between `du ... /1/2/n` and `du ... /1/2/n/*`.

Comment: @they, well, your point with hard-links was really good indeed! I've checked and there are hard-links in in the source directory (thousands of hard links!). And if I used `du -l` switch I'm getting same folder sizes. Thanks, I've learned some new today ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @they in the comments under OP, I've found the root cause. Original source volume contained lots of hard-linked directories/files and they all were copied to new volume as new standalone (fixed) directories/files.

There were actually two things that helped me to understand the problem:

- `rsync` doesn't respect hard links by default. **Lessons learned:** run `rsync` with `--hard-links` switch, potentially also with `--sparse` switch to handle smaller files efficiently.
- `du` doesn't include size of hard-linked files by default. **Lessons learned:** run `du -l` switch to count size of all files, incl. those hard-linked. Similarly to sizes what `ls` displays.

Without knowing these two aspects and I wouldn't know if my files are synced correctly.